# Index display order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, indexing, scaffold

I have a search form that returns an array of ids in a random order, depending of which element has more key words in the search. In the index they appear ordered by the smallest id.

For example:

```
def search
    ids = [13,8,2,4,7]
    items.where("id in ?", ids)
  end
```

In the index action of my controller I have something like

```
@items = Items.search
```

but the items keep being displayed in an order like `[2,4,7,8,13]` in the index table.

How do I display the items in the same order I'm querying them in my search function?

Comment: Without knowing anything about your structure I would add another column, items_id, to your database table. What I believe is that :id will always come out in order whereas :items_id can vary.

Comment: yes i also thought to add that column it just didn't seem right you know? there has to be a way i can get those items in the order i'm querying them... but if i don't find a way i will have to create that column

Comment: Is there any `default_scope` declaration on that model ?

Comment: the thing is that it looks for them in the exact order but returns the items in order i have no idea why, i think it's got something to do with the "in" clause of the query i don't know.... and i don't think that there is a default_scope, but then again i'm super new with rails so i don't know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To sort based on an existing index, you need to do something like this:

```
ids = [13,8,2,4,7]
id_positions = Hash[ids.each_with_index.to_a]

items.where(id: ids).sort_by do |r|
  id_positions[r.id]
end
```

This returns them to their original order using a mapping table.

Note that this is incompatible with lazy iteration, they all need to be pulled in to be manipulated. It should work with pagination where you're dealing with subsets of the results, though.

The `sort_by` call can be done on any Array-type set, so even results from a Search would work.

Comment: thanks i knew there had to be a way! worked like a charm

Answer (score 4):

There is a little bit shorter way of accomplishing the same result as tadman's answer.

```
ids = [13,8,2,4,7]
items = Item.find(ids) #or whatever your search criteria includes...
items.index_by(&:id).values_at(*ids) #returns in ids order from above...
```

Comment: Rails does introduce some handy methods like `index_by` that are totally worth using.